# Ros threading to have multiple processes?

Tags: ros, c++, multi-thread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So basically, what I want to have is this:

1. Have ROS collect data, and process this data into a vector. (This is done)
2. Once the data has been recorded, write the vector to a text file (Not done)

The problem that I have is, how do I stop ros from spinning? How can I then just simply run the function which writes the text to the file?

I've been thinking along the lines of threading, I create a thread that subscribes handles the callback function and another thread that handles writing to the text file. So in essence, the plan would be to have `thread1` run for a set amount of time, then halt `thread1` and begin to start `thread2`

Is this possible using ROS? And, is this the only method to solving the above?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120421/ros-threading-to-have-multiple-processes?/) by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-01-21**:
Do you want to do 1) and 2) repeatedly, or just once? In any case try checking out the suggestion by @ahendrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand your problem correctly, use `ros::spinOnce()` to manually spin. Somewhat along the lines of:

```
while(ros::ok() && !got_all_data) {
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
}
```

Alternatively if you want to collect all data first and write afterwards, just use `ros::spin();` and write the file afterwards. Ctrl-C should stop the spinning. (You might want to test that before doing something critical).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why not record the data you're interested in to a bag file, and then process that bag file later using python bag API?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1